# brew install boost does not give correct directory structure, no python tutorial

Tags: python, c++, boost

I installed boost on my Macbook Pro laptop using `brew install boost` and it proceeded without errors.

```
$ brew install boost
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/boost/1.56.0.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring boost-1.56.0.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0: 10471 files, 438M
```

However, when I check my directory structure:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0/
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json  include/              lib/
```

It does not match the directory structure for boost as [shown on the official documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). In particular, I can't find the files needed to build `boost.python` and the [files related to the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/building.html). Has anyone else run into this problem, and if so, how can I find the `libs/python/example/quickstart/` directory?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install Boost with Python support. A vanilla `brew install boost` won't do this for you. If you have the, as of right now, latest version of Homebrew (0.9.5), you can do:

```
brew install boost-python
```

Otherwise, you should use:

```
brew install boost --with-python
```

Second, the directory structure you linked is for the 1.41.0 Windows version of the Boost distribution. If you're installing the latest Boost distribution on a Unix system like OS X, you should be looking at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Finally, there is no `libs/python/example/quickstart` when you install Boost with Brew. Everything you need to use Boost.Python is in the library binaries that are installed on your system when you use `brew install boost-python`. When you install Boost using Homebrew, you aren't getting the source code ultimately. Homebrew builds the libraries for you, so there's no need to "build Boost.Python".